# How to integrate dependency injection with custom decorators

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm trying to create a decorator that requires dependency injection. 
For example:

```
@Injectable()
class UserService{
  @TimeoutAndCache(1000)
  async getUser(id:string):Promise<User>{
     // Make a call to db to get all Users
  }
}
```

The @TimeoutAndCache returns a new promise which does the following:

1. if call takes longer than 1000ms, returns a rejection and when the call completes, it stores to redis (so that it can be fetched next time).
2. If call takes less than 1000ms, simply returns the result

```
export const TimeoutAndCache = function timeoutCache(ts: number, namespace) {
  return function log(
    target: object,
    propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>,
  ) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value; // save a reference to the original method
    descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
      // pre
      let timedOut = false;
      // run and store result
      const result: Promise<object> = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
      const task = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
          if (!timedOut) {
            timedOut = true;
            console.log('timed out before finishing');
            reject('timedout');
          }
        }, ts);
        result.then(res => {
          if (timedOut) {
            // store in cache
            console.log('store in cache');
          } else {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            // return the result
            resolve(res);
          }
        });
      });
      return task;
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
};
```

I need to inject a RedisService to save the evaluated result. 
One way I could inject Redis Service in to the UserService, but seems kind ugly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should consider using an `Interceptor` instead of a custom decorator as they run earlier in the Nest pipeline and support dependency injection by default.

However, because you want to both pass values (for cache timeout) as well as resolve dependencies you'll have to use the `mixin` pattern.

```js
import {
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  mixin,
  NestInterceptor,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { TestService } from './test/test.service';

@Injectable()
export abstract class CacheInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  protected abstract readonly cacheDuration: number;

  constructor(private readonly testService: TestService) {}

  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    call$: Observable<any>,
  ): Observable<any> {
    // Whatever your logic needs to be

    return call$;
  }
}

export const makeCacheInterceptor = (cacheDuration: number) =>
  mixin(
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-classes-per-file
    class extends CacheInterceptor {
      protected readonly cacheDuration = cacheDuration;
    },
  );
```

You would then be able to apply the Interceptor to your handler in a similar fashion:

```js
@Injectable()
class UserService{
  @UseInterceptors(makeCacheInterceptor(1000))
  async getUser(id:string):Promise<User>{
     // Make a call to db to get all Users
  }
}
```

Comment: I having a tough time getting the interceptor to work, even the simple logging interceptor on [NestJS docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) does not work on any  method in a class. It seems to only work on my @Controller annotated methods?

Would you be kind enough to add a test case to this?

Comment: @jesse-carter Where did you learn about the `mixin` function? I haven't seen it in the docs (https://docs.nestjs.com)

Comment: Please, remove or edit your answer not to confuse people. It's not possible to apply an interceptor for something that is not a controller https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1923